# Conformal mapping between two disks with holes.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a conformal (analytical and bijective) mapping from $\mathbb{D} \setminus B(a_1,r_1)$ to $\mathbb{D} \setminus B(a_2,r_2)$ (substracted circles lie inside $\mathbb{D}$ completely) I need to prove that this mapping is Möbius transformation. I thought about if it's possible to continue the map to the whole $\mathbb{D}$-automorphism and thus deduce that it can be only in form of Möbius transformation. Another my attempt was suggesting that it should be a disk automorphism, finding it's form from information where $f$ maps some points and then showing somehow that the corresponding Möbius transformation should be the same map. But i don't know how to proceed further that these vague words in any of these variants.

Comment: answer not quite correct so will fix it when back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sketch of a proof - will fill in details but recommend to try and do it:

Step 1: use the Mobius automorphism of the disc $M_1(z)=\frac{z-b_1}{1-\bar b_1 z_1}$, where $b_1^2-(a_1-r_1\bar a_1)b_1-r_1=0, |b_1| <1$ (the quadratic has a root in the unit disc as the absolute value of root product is at most $1-|a_1|<1$)  to send the circle $C(a_1,r_1)$ to a circle centered at the origin and leave $\mathbb D$ invariant (this follows from the general formula of the center of a circle under a Mobius transform - in general, it is enough to know this exists and that you can always solve for $b_1$ when $a_1,r_1$ are given as above - note that sending $a_1$ to $0$ with a disc automorphism doesn't guarantee that the image circle has its center at $0$ as only the hyperbolic distance is preserved not the Euclidean one!).

Same with $M_2, z_2$. Then $M_(B(a_1,r_1))=B(0, k_1)$ and same with $M_2$ hence we get $g=M_2 \circ f \circ M_1^{-1}$ conformal map from annulus between $k_1,1$ to the annulus between $k_2,1$ and it is enough to prove that is Mobius

Step 2: It is a standard (proof not that hard using harmonic functions for example and will provide if requested) that this implies $k_1=k_2$ and $g(z)=\alpha z, |\alpha| =1$ or $g(z)=\alpha \frac{k_1}{z}$ 
(the last part is easy as up to inversion we can assume $g$ maps the small circle to the small circle and the unit circle to the unit circle and then $g/z$ is clearly constant as is non zero and $1$ in absolute value on the boundary, the equality of the radiuses is trickier)

(edit later - sketch of the proof that $A(r,1), A(q,1), r,q <1$ are conformally equivalent iff $r=q$ using harmonic functions - another standard proof can be given using the reflection principle)

Let $f$ conformal equivalence between $A(r,1), A(q,1) ,r,q <1$ and by composing with an inversion if needed we can assume $|f(z)| \to 1, |z| \to 1, |f(z)| \to q, |z| \to r$ and let $u(z)=\log |f(z)|- c\log |z|, c\log r=\log q$ which is harmonic and satisfies $u(z) \to 0, z\to \partial A(1,r)$ hence by the maximum/minimum principle for real harmonic functions $u=0$, $|f(z)|=|z|^c$

But using a local holomorphic logarithm $g_w=\log f$ near any point $w \in A(1,r)$
(may not exist globally on the annulus but exists on a small disc $D_w$) and noting that $|f(z)|^{\frac{1}{c}}=|z|$ we get $|\frac{1}{z}e^{\frac{g_w}{c}}|=1$ on $D_w$ hence $e^{\frac{g_w}{c}}=\alpha_w z, |\alpha_w|=1$ and by diferentiating $\frac{f'}{f}=\frac{c}{z}$ on $D_w$. This doesn't depend on $w$ hence it holds on $A(1,r)$ and by the argument principle (or just integrate on a circle within $A(1,r)$ and use that $f$ is conformal equivalence so LHS=$\pm 2\pi i$, while RHS =$2 \pi i c$) it follows that $\pm 1 =c$ and since $c>0$ as $\log r, \log q <0$, $c=1$ and $r=q$ Done!

Comment: Discovery that we can move the hole inside of the disk was quite unexpected for me, thanks. I'm still trying to understand how did you got the formula for $b_1$. I don't know general formula for Mobius transform on circles but will the following argument work instead? We can always rotate circle such way that centres will be on real line, and it seems that system on automorphism of the disk coef. $b_1$ that will move $[a-r; a+r]$ to $[-R; R]$ for some $R$ will have a solution on real line. Am i correct?

Comment: the formula is just the general transformation of the center a "generic" circle under a "generic" Mobius transform (so they do not interfere with one another and is obtained by doing the computations step by step as any generic Mobus transform is a standard composition of translation, inversion, translation - really not worth spending too much time on unless one really needs the exact numbers) and it's just a rough way of showing the reault we need that we can use a disc automorphism to send a circle inside the unit disc to a circle centered at origin and viceversa -

Comment: It seems that i can't think of any way of proving the second step.

Comment: sketched a proof using harmonic functions

Comment: It seems to me that $a_w$ is a function of z, how did you moved to the case that it is constant?

Comment: Why u(z) is harmonic? I tried to check it by hand but it's not trivial for me.

Comment: when you take the logarithmic derivative $a_w$ disappears (appears both numerator and denominator); $u=\Re(\log f -c \log z)$ is the real part of of a holomorphic function near any point as both $\log f, \log z$ are defined around any point of the annulus as noted later, although they may not be defined globally on the whole annulus as that is not simply connected - for $\log |z|$ it is a good exercise to check that by hand using the polar form of the Laplacian and the polar C-R